# Dapper escape sp_tables procedure error

Tags: c#, dapper

Am trying to use dapper to execute the `sp_tables` stored procedure and escape the procedure name as follows but still getting error.
    `var procName = @"sp_tables @table_type = ""'type', 'TABLE'""";`
    `var tables = con.Query(procName, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference this how I solved it.
`var tables = con.Query("sp_tables", new { table_type = @"""'type', 'TABLE'""" }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`